# Django template for loop is empty in another block

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a function in my `view.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def gpd(request,pk):

    # get gpd by id
    current_gpd = get_gpd(pk)

    # get current campaign year                                                                     #TODO check types
    current_campaign = get_campaign(current_gpd.gpd_year)

    # get all corporate goals for current campaign
    corp_goals = CorporateGoal.objects.filter(gpd_year=current_campaign.year)

    compl_weight = []
    for goal in corp_goals:
        compl_weight.append(goal.corp_factor_weight*current_gpd.bonus.corporate_component//100)
    corporate_goals = zip(corp_goals, compl_weight)

    

    if is_manager(request)!=None:
        team = get_team(request)
        context = {'gpd':current_gpd, 
                   'corporate_goals':corporate_goals,
                   }
        return render(request, 'app/gpd_forms/form_gpd.html', context)
    else:
        context = {'gpd':current_gpd, 
                   'corporate_goals':corporate_goals, 
                   }
        return render(request, 'app/gpd_forms/form_gpd.html', context)
```

As you can see, in context I have `corporate_goal`.
My `form_gpd.html`:

```
{% extends 'app/navbar/main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

{% include 'app/slidebar/gpd_form_slidebar.html' %}

    <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
        <div class="row">
        <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
                    {% include 'app/gpd_blocks/corporate_goal.html' %}
                </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
        <div class="row">
        <div id="section5" class="container-fluid">
                    {% include 'app/gpd_blocks/summary.html' %}
                </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    </div>

    


</div>
    

{% endblock %}
```

for example in corporate block I am executing next:

```
{% load static %}


  

{% block content %}

<div class="row" id="super">
    <p>&nbsp</p>
</div>
<div class="row" id="super">
    <div class="col-11" style="color: ivory; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.3em;">
        CORPORATE GOALS BLOCK
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="super">
    <p>&nbsp</p>
</div>

{% for goal, compl_weight in corporate_goals %} 
<hr style="height:2px;border:none;color:rgb(87, 124, 161);background-color:rgb(87, 124, 161);" />

<!-- Corporate goal section-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Corp. Goal: {{ goal.corp_goal_title }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <div>
                {% if goal.corp_factor_rate %}
                    <p style="color:mediumspringgreen">rated</p>
                {% else %}
                    <p style="color:indianred">unrated</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div style="margin-inline-start:auto">
                {{compl_weight}} % of total score 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- Tabs for details-->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#det1{{ goal.id }}">Goal Details</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#det2{{ goal.id }}">Other Details</a></li>

</ul>

<!-- Tabs content for details-->
<div class="tab-content" >
    <!--First tab-->
    <div id="det1{{ goal.id }}" class="tab-pane fade show active">
        <div class="row">
            <!--Column 1-->
            <div class="col">
                <table class="table-bordless" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <td width="50"></td>
                            <td>{{ goal.start_date }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Weight</th>
                            <td width="20"></td>
                            <td>{{ goal.corp_factor_weight }} %</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><p>&nbsp</p></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="color:dimgray">Goal description</th>
                            <td width="18"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="row">
                    <textarea class="form-control" readonly title="Description" style="background-color:aliceblue !important;">{{goal.corp_goal_description}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Column 2-->
            <div class="col">
                <table class="table-bordless" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            <td width="50"></td>
                            <td>{{ goal.end_date }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Factor Rate</th>
                            <td width="50"></td>
                            <td>
                                {% if goal.corp_factor_rate %}
                                    {{ goal.corp_factor_rate }}
                                {% else %}
                                <div style="color:mediumspringgreen; font-weight: bold;">ongoing...</div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><p>&nbsp</p></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="color:dimgray">Goal comment</th>
                            <td width="18"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                
                <div class="row">
                    <textarea class="form-control" readonly title="Comment" style="background-color:aliceblue !important;">{{goal.corp_goal_comment}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Second tab-->
    <div id="det2{{ goal.id }}" class="tab-pane fade" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <p>Factor for Goal Achievement:</p>
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Factor</th>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <td>{{ goal.corp_factor_0 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Factor</th>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <td>{{ goal.corp_factor_1 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Factor</th>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <td>{{ goal.corp_factor_2 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Factor</th>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <td>{{ goal.corp_factor_3 }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />





{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And it works perfectly. But when in last block `summary` I want to use `corporate_goals` one more time - I have nothing on my page, looks like `corporate_goals` is not exist.

my `summary.html`

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    <p>123</p>
</div>


<div class="row">
    {% for goal, compl_weight in corporate_goals %} 
        {{ goal.corp_goal_title }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>123</p>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Even If I copy all my code from `corporate_goal.html` into summary - I will have nothing. Why ?

Comment: What is the difference between `corporate_goals` and `corporate_goal` in the context? Is it a typo or a mistake?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's my TYPO in question [have edited]

Comment: Do something like this {% for goal in corporate_goals.all %}  {{ goal.corp_goal_title }} {% endfor %}

Comment: I have added .all and still nothing

Comment: when I am doing smth like that `{% if corporate_goals %}
        True
        {% for goal, compl_weight in corporate_goals %} 
        {{ goal.corp_goal_title }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        False
    {% endif %}` I have True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was in zip objects. When we are iterating through a zip object it is exhausted and you cannot iterate through it again. So, solution is `corporate_goals = list(zip(corp_goals, compl_weight))`. Anyway, thank you, @LaCharcaSoftware, for the advice, I've changed my structure to avoid duplication with `block content`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that your html structure has no sense. You have three {% block content %}. Please, delete the content blocks of your include files (corporate_goal.html and summary.html) and check if this is the problem. I think that one of your content block is overriding the other one.

Just to clarify, when you use the "include tag" is like you were pasting the code from other file. So imagine the result. You have a block content that contains two other block contents inside it.

Comment: i have deleted all nested block content and also include, but it doesn't help

Comment: I'm still thinking that the problem is the html structure. Try to write other html template just with the forloops and some fields to test. If a forloop works once, it has to work twice. You can also see the html code of the rendered page by right-clicking in the browser and clicking "View page source code", and check if there is something wrong.

Comment: now in my `form_gpd.html` i have only two same include `{% include 'app/gpd_blocks/corporate_goal.html' %}`.  In my corporate_goal.html only: `{% for goal, compl_weight in corporate_goals %} 
 <div class="row">
  {{ goal.corp_goal_title }}
 </div>
{% endfor %}`. First include correctly display the value, the second one display nothing. Why, I can't understand